# Verify the number of opening and closing brackets

Tags: c++

Need to write a function that checks the validity of the placement of braces in a row.
If the opening parenthesis corresponds to much the same closing, the function should return true.
Example of the input string: "`(())) ()) ()`"

Posted two variants of solutions. Which one is better, and there is a better way to solve the problem?

1:

```
bool parenthesis(char myString[80]) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; myString[i]; ++i) {
        if (myString[i] == '(')
            k++;
        if (myString[i] == ')')
            k--;
    }
    if (k == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

2:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "(()))())()";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << (std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '(') == 
                  std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ')') && *str.begin() ==
                  '(' && *str.rbegin() == ')')
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It'll return true for this input: `()))))((((()`

Comment: make sure k never goes negative, it would work for this `)(`

Comment: Is this for school?  You code will not detect invalid matches like:  "))((".  Did you recently learn about stacks?   Because one would come in handy to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both seem not optimal as they would validy strings as

```
()))((()
```

I would probably do the counting thing but check additionally that the number is always non-negative.

```
bool validate_parantheses(const std::string& str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : str)
    {
        if(c == '(')
            count++;
        else if(c == ')')
            count--;
        if(count < 0)
            return false;
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do by just adding one for `(`, subtracting one for `)`, while taking care the sum never goes negative. At the end it has to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 is more readable and allows you to fix the bug (which is in both solutions) more easily.  See the added "return false".

```
bool parenthesis(char myString[80]) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; myString[i]; ++i) {
        if (myString[i] == '(')
            k++;
        if (myString[i] == ')')
            k--;
        if (k<0) // This was missing from your original algorithm.
            return false;
    }
    if (k == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Note that it would be more complicated if it needed to support any real-world parsing problems eg different types of braces: ([[()]]){}{{(())}}

If you had problem like this, the "stack" solution someone else mentioned would work better because you can push the open braces onto the stack and when you find a close brace, pop the open off the top of the stack and verify it's the correct type.